# Problems with launching the physical device in android studio

Tags: android-studio

After i connect the device onto my android studio yet, then when I running and build Its return the code

Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed: INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE

List of apks:
[0] 'D:\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\apk\debug\app-debug.apk'
The device already has a newer version of this application.
in the editor
I try to fix this things with some article in this site but nothing working else

In the corner of screen it has this too that i dont know what is it exactly of meaning:
failed to commit install session 495050153 with command package install-commit 495050153 .Error:INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE

So,[this is the problem when running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qU43K.png)
and
[after click Ok then its getting error thiss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPYV9.png)
, and also I when open tab running devices its still apppearing just only run this debug then its get this error
.Thank you for helping me this problems

Answer (score 1):

You can uninstall the application from your device first and then install the fresh one .

Comment: so i try this but seemly it still has thius problem